# Can't understant instruction strcmp() in this code

Tags: c, strcmp, ctf

I have some problem understanding a code.

Can you please help me to understand this line of code :

```
strcmp("admin",*(char **)(users + (long)local_24 * 0x10 + 8));
```

Full code :

```
void test(void){
  int iVar1;
  long in_FS_OFFSET;
  int local_24;
  undefined1 *local_20;
  FILE *local_18;
  long local_10;

  local_10 = *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28);
  printf("\n[+] User ID to login with: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  __isoc99_scanf(&DAT_00102079,&local_24);
  getchar();
  if ((local_24 < 0) || (nb_users <= local_24)) {
    puts("[-] Invalid user ID.");
  }
  else {
    local_20 = users + (long)local_24 * 0x10;
    iVar1 = strcmp("admin",*(char **)(users + (long)local_24 * 0x10 + 8));
    if (iVar1 == 0) {
      puts("[+] Welcome back, admin!");
      local_18 = fopen("flag.txt","r");
      while( true ) {
        iVar1 = fgetc(local_18);
        if ((char)iVar1 == -1) break;
        putchar((int)(char)iVar1);
      }
    }
    else {
      puts("[-] You are not admin.");
    }
  }
  if (local_10 != *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28)) {
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
    __stack_chk_fail();
  }
  return;
}
```

(Users represents a username that the user can choose.)

Thank you !

Comment: `strcmp()` compares the first and second arguments. It returns `0` if they are equal. So your statement checks if `*(char **)(users + (long)local_24 * 0x10 + 8)` is/points to `"admin"`

Comment: `strcmp` is fully documented [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).  It's hard to tell what that specific line of code does without more details.  What is `users`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp()` compares two strings `(const char *)`.  It returns zero if the two strings are identical and for your code non-zero if they are not.  See [strcmp(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for more information.  The first string is `"admin"` and the 2nd string is `*(char **)(users + (long)local_24 * 0x10 + 8)`.  The initial `*` dereference the `(char **)` so you have a string. You are not telling us what `users` is but my guess is that it is an array of structs (serialized to a file).  `(long)local_24` is a count of structs each `0x10` (16) in size, and `8` is the offset into the struct. This should use `#define` and/or `sizeof()` to be more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I've now understood how the program works, but do you know what does 0x10 represents ?

Comment: My guess is length of struct user (possible something that is 8 bytes followed by another 8 bytes string). You would have to inspect users with a debugger or print it out to see what it is.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, users is a username (a string) that the user can choose.

Comment: "The first string is `"admin"` and the 2nd string is `*(char **)(users + (long)local_24 * 0x10 + 8)`." lacks clarity for a leaner.  `"admin"` is a _string_.  `*(char **)(users + (long)local_24 * 0x10 + 8)` is a _pointer_.  `strcmp(a,b)` compares 2 _strings_: what `a,b` point to.  `strcmp(a,b)` does not compare `a,b`.  Keeping the distinction between a _string_ and a _pointer_ is useful for learners.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I used the definition from the man page "compares the two strings" which makes no mention of pointers (other than as a analogy for `const char *`).  Not sure talking about pointers makes it more clear, but maybe op will weight in.